# One point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $K$ denote the one point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $K$ is homeomorphic to $\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. I want to know if $K$ is extremally disconnected (that is, if the closure of every open set in $K$ is also open). It seems like this would be the case, since any open set would have the form $\{1/k:k\geq n\}$ for some $n$, $\{1/k:j\leq k\leq n\}$ for some $n,j$, or ${0}\cup\{1/k:k\geq n\}$ for some $n$. In the first case, then closure is $\{0\}\cup\{1/k:k\geq n\}$, but the compliment of this set is $\{1,...,1/n-1\}$ which is closed, and hence, $\{0\}\cup\{1/k:k\geq n\}$ is also open. But I have reason to believe this result is not true.

Comment: $K$ is metric, so if it were extremally disconnected, then it would be trivial (as [Wiki says here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space)). But $\{0\}$ is not open. Anyway, it is a good question and I hadn't realised your mistake until Cameron Buie posted a fantastic answer.

Comment: I meant discrete, no trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not extremally disconnected, and you've missed many of the possible open sets. For example, $\{2,4\}$ is open, as is the set of all the odd natural numbers. In general, the open sets will be

- *any* subset of $\Bbb N$ (as a union of open singletons), or
- any subset of $K$ whose complement in $K$ is a finite subset of $\Bbb N$ (since those are the closed, compact subsets of $\Bbb N$).

In fact, the set $O$ of all the odds gives us an example to show that $K$ is not extremally disconnected. $O$ is open in $K,$ and its closure is $O\cup\{\star\},$ where $\star$ is the unique element of $K\setminus\Bbb N.$ However, its closure is not a subset of $\Bbb N,$ and its closure's complement (the set of all even natural numbers) is not finite, so its closure is not open.

Comment: Ah yes I see, thank you Cameron

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: I have expanded my answer slightly to explicitly categorize the open subsets of $K.$